# Communication between Android Emulator on VM and Host

Tags: android-emulator, virtual-machine

I have an *Android Emulator* running on an *Ubuntu VM* that is hosted on *Win7*.

Now, I want to reach an IP address that is hosted on my Win7 from the Android Emulator.

I can reach the address from the Ubuntu guest machine, but I can't from the emulator.

Win7 Host IP - 10.100.102.2

Ubuntu Guest IP - 10.0.2.15 (NAT Network Adapter)

IP Address - 10.100.102.2:21000

I'm guessing that I have to add a route in the emulator for it to work. I've tried to route throught these [special addresses](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#networkaddresses), but it didn't work :\

```
ip route add 10.100.102.2/32 via 10.0.2.1 dev eth0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem wasn't with the routing.

It was with the fact that both the VM and the Emulator were configured with a NAT Network Adapter under the same subnet *10.0.2.0/24*.

The moment I changed the VMs network adapter to *Bridged*, everything started to work.